# where is op_addition in [int,float,double]

Tags: c#

Dummy code:

```
public object Addition(object a, object b)
{
    var type = a.GetType();
    var op = type.GetMethod("op_Addition", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    return op.Invoke(null, new object[] { a, b });
}
```

This method complains with int/float/double,that can't find these methods(op_Addition).

**So how to build a general addition method?**

Comment: You can do this with `dynamic`, if you have .net 4 available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they're not custom operators which exist as members like that - there are built-in IL instructions instead.

(The same is *almost* true for string concatenation, except there the C# compiler builds a call to `string.Concat`.)

If you're using C# 4 and .NET 4, the simplest approach is to use dynamic typing:

```
public dynamic Addition(dynamic x, dynamic y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

For earlier versions, you'll need to special-case certain types :(

It's not clear what your context is, but you may find Marc Gravell's [article on generic operators](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html) interesting.

Comment: Thanks @jon,I am using mono version,I think I should cast [int ,double] to float first with these types.