# I need something like Add(object arg0, object arg1)

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, unity-game-engine

I have a baseclass `MyBaseClass` that has two methods:

```
public abstract class Baseclass
{
    public abstract Type GetProvidedType();
    public abstract object GetProvidedData();
}
```

There are some implementations of that baseclass, and they all provide completely different data. Some may provide an int, some may provide a Vector2, or some complex type. I can't say what at compile time.

What I would like to do, is adding the returns of two different GetProvidedData() calls.
Something like:

```
MyBaseClass provider0 = GetProvider(0);
MyBaseClass provider1 = GetProvider(1);
return provider0.GetProvidedData() + provider1.GetProvidedData();
```

That, of course, leads to error CS0019: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'object'.

- I tried using the dynamic keyword. But that's not implemented enough yet in Unity (I'm using 5.1.1f1).
- I tried using reflection. Like making GetProvidedData() a generic method, getting the MethodInfo via reflection, using MakeGenericMethod, and calling that. Which of course, when invoked, provides me with an effing object again.
- Even Convert.ChangeType returns an object. Which, at that point, is useless to me.
- I tried getting the + operator via reflection (it's a method with the name "op_Addition"), but that won't work for native types like int.

Any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: Does unity support generics? If so BaseClass<T> could return T for GetProvidedData() and MyBaseClass could implement BaseClass<int>.

Comment: Unity does support generics, but they are not really of any use, because I don't know the type at compile time. Only at runtime. And obviously I can't do a call like Add<GetProvidedType()>(...);

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to build an Add function that takes an inderterminate number of parameters and uses type checking to add.

This approach is quite slow execution wise, requires each support type to be implemented manually and require that you know the return value type. But it works.

```
    using System;

    namespace AddExample
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                float result = Add(20, 20.3f);

                Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            private static float Add(params object[] values)
            {
                float result = 0;

                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    if (value is int)
                    {
                        result += (int) value;
                    }
                    else if (value is float)
                    {
                        result += (float) value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new NotSupportedException("Add does not support type");
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Related question if you want to go the generic way: [where is op_addition in [int,float,double]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155444/where-is-op-addition-in-int-float-double)

Comment: Hm, seems like I'll have to do something like that. I just wish there was another solution, because I would like to offer my users the option to provide their own implementations. And with your solution, or the one @Fabjan recommended, I'd prohibit any addition that has not been taken care off beforehand.

Comment: @TommyCore Did you check Mark Gravells article on generic operators? http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html

Comment: Interesting article, thank you. Unfortunately, it is of limited use. "What about compile-time checking? Yes; good point. Put simply; it can't do this." - which is exactly my problem. I can't call that function without knowing my T at compile time. But it makes me question if I don't have a general misconception in my approach...

Comment: Actually - I know nothing about Linq, but if I can rewrite this method that is stated in the article to have a signature like "static T0 Add<T0,T1>(T0 a, T1 b)", I could try and get the appropriate method via reflection using MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod()... That might just do the trick. Gotta do some research and learning.