# C# implicit operator generic minus/plus int

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, operator-keyword, implicit

I have this class in C#:

```
public class MyClass<A, B> where B : OtherClass<A>
{
    [SerializeField] A _value = default;
        
    public A Value 
    {
        get => _value;
        set => _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator A(MyClass<A, B> variable)
    {
        return variable.Value;
    }
}
```

I'ld really like to being able to do this:

```
MyClass<int, OtherClass<int>> myVar = new MyClass<int, OtherClass<int>>();
myVar.Value = 5;
myVar -= 3; // this is actually not valid and I wish to make it valid.
```

Is there a way I don't know to make this?
Tell me if you need any further informations.

Comment: There are only a limited number of types you can do this with anyway, so perhaps you should just create separate type for them and forget generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Since there is no interface for even *having* an `operator -`, there is no way to express that `A` must have an `operator -`. And with that possibility gone, there is no way to create your own `operator -` calling `A`'s operator minus.

Comment: That's a mess. I really hoped to miss any knowledge about this. Thank you so much anyway. I'll accept this as soon as possible.

Comment: Well, technically, you *could* probably use some dynamic/reflection magic to call `operator-` on `A`, but I think we all agree that this should not be done.

Comment: Indeed, you would lose the compile-time support for generics. That solution, while probably working, would be unable to produce compile time errors when not working.

Comment: @Heinzi You can't do it with reflection either, because their is no actual function `-` *at all*, it's a compiler intrinsic for all integer and float types.

Comment: @Charlieface: [Good point.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11155444/87698) `dynamic` should work, though. (Again, not saying it's a good idea.)